# shut off htmlpurifier upgrade message

Tags: drupal, htmlpurifier

In drupal, keep getting an upgrade message all over site from htmlpurifier that a 4.0 is available. Ran upgrades (uploaded files and ran update.php) but still have message. No finds on this when I googled around.

Supposedly a flush.php in a maintenace folder will flush it's cache (which is invconveniently separate from the rest of Drupal's cache), but trying to execute in browser gets me an error.

Either upgrade is bad or needs cache flushed, or just shut off this message. Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install both the updated *module* and the *library*?  The module is [here](http://drupal.org/project/htmlpurifier) while the library you should download  [here](http://htmlpurifier.org).

Comment: I did not realize the diff tween the 2, and I now have the htmlpurifier 2.0 module enabled, and the /modules/htmlpurifier/library/htmlpurifier-4.0.0/et all uploaded. Still have the message, still don't see a flush button or config entry in my site configs. What am I still doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, I walked away for a few hours and now it works fine. It was confusing cuz the library download also contains a folder called 'library'. I think they need to sort this out better. I had to put the htmlpurifier-4.0.0 folder itself in the htmlpurifier/library/ folder, where you see other version folders also (like 3.2.0, etc.)

Thanks for the help!